# node.js Create initialization vector (IV) from random source

Tags: node.js

How to create a initialization vector (IV) from a random source in NodeJS, like I do in PHP as follows:

```
$iv = mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC), MCRYPT_RAND);
```

In NodeJS I thought `crypto.createCipheriv` could help but no.

Answer (score 41):

You are on the right track and will still need to use:

```
Crypto.createCipheriv()
```

The function that can generate you a randomized initialization vector would be:

```
Crypto.randomBytes(16)
```

The 16 signifies the number of bytes required to fulfil the required length of the vector.

To give an example:

```
var iv = Crypto.randomBytes(16);
var cipher = Crypto.createCipheriv('aes-128-cbc', new Buffer(<128 bit password>), iv);
var encrypted = cipher.update(clearText);
var finalBuffer = Buffer.concat([encrypted, cipher.final()]);
//Need to retain IV for decryption, so this can be appended to the output with a separator (non-hex for this example)
var encryptedHex = iv.toString('hex') + ':' + finalBuffer.toString('hex')
```

For the sake of completeness, here's an example for decrypting the above `encryptedHex`

```
var encryptedArray = encryptedHex.split(':');
var iv = new Buffer(encryptedArray[0], 'hex');
var encrypted = new Buffer(encryptedArray[1], 'hex');
var decipher = Crypto.createDecipheriv('aes-128-cbc', new Buffer(<128 bit password>), iv);
var decrypted = decipher.update(encrypted);
var clearText = Buffer.concat([decrypted, decipher.final()]).toString();
```

Comment: `new Buffer(<128 bit password>)` see PBKDF2 for how to do this effectively.

https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_pbkdf2_password_salt_iterations_keylen_digest_callback

Comment: If you wanted to decrypt data down the line; not in memory. Would you store the secret and the IV in a db. Then when you decrypt pull the IV from the db. Does the IV need to be different every time? Is there a way I can just pick an IV and use that every time?

Comment: IV must be different every time, it can be very dangerous to reuse it more than once

Comment: Need of IV originated itself from the fact that IV should be that segment of encryption which will be random and can't be observed as a pattern under repetitive use of algo-cycles to start hacking with.

Comment: for me it worked like this. `CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.random(128 / 8);`