# AES256 password and iv, the right way

Tags: node.js, cryptography, cryptojs

I want to create and manage user sessions with AES256 encrypted tokens.

I am using node's crypto library and followed this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25427935/node-js-create-initialization-vector-iv-from-random-source).

I am using this to create session token that will be sent to frontend and stored in the backend for verification purpose and the data is stringified JSON.

Here I see two things one is `password` and other is `iv`.

so two questions,

1. Is the iv is safe to sent to frontend `(iv + "." + encData)`?
2. How should the password be generated? How about a SHA256 of (e.g. user's password that I store in db at signup)

This way I will be using a different password for each user. Is this approach correct?

P.S. Both of the answers below helped a lot, If you are here, do read all the comments and attached So question and the linked articles.

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to re-invent encrypted [JSON Web Tokens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON_Web_Token).

Comment: @robertklep you are kind of correct, I have used JWTs before but I wanted to use something different for some reasons, unpopularity of JWT nowadays (just google) and I want to implement a custom expiry feature.

Comment: Any solution that you make yourself will be far less popular than JWT's, because there will be only _one_ institution that uses it: you. Also, JWT's are at least standardized, and at least with [`jsonwebtoken`](https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken) you can have it ignore `exp` claims so you can implement your own.

Comment: I really want to just use AES256 and as for standardisation I am using standard crypto libraries cipher/decipher function and implementing AES 256. so is that bad in any way? I am using something that is tested and implementing only my expiry system which again if I use for jwt then I am essentially doing the same and maybe even worse as I will be intentinally breaking jwt. What are your thoughts?

Comment: From what I know, you don't _have_ to use `exp` claims and you can just make up your own claim to handle custom expiry, that won't break the JWT standard. And as for AES256, I'm also pretty sure that you can use that algorithm to encrypt JWT's.

Comment: I really don't see aes256 in here https://jwt.io unless ES256 is aes256 which i highly doubt?

Comment: You have to search for a library that supports _encryption_ rather than just verification: https://npms.io/search?q=jwe

Comment: ok ill check for the same and maybe use something but on a first glance i could not find appropriate library. the ones I found are rarely used. But thanks for your suggestions and maybe I will find my answer in jwe but I still highly doubt as jwe is just encryption and so is crypto cipher and there is no clear advantage of jwe at that point. but i will surely increase the research are and maybe even update the question/answer here if I find something that is more interesting.
Thanks

Comment: "P.S. I am implementing the highest possible security measure for a financial institute." And you need to ask these kind of entry level questions? Sorry, but are you **sure** you are the right person for this job?

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Well I am not a Security Professional and If I am asking something is because in hope to get good expert views from "Professionals" such as yourself, instead of being mocked Sir. With all due respect, every one learns this stuff along the way. you may judge me due to the nature of question asked but you can never know what situation a user is in or what kind of knowledge a person has or has-not, anyways, if you want to contribute, please do else thank you for your input.

Comment: Right! But remember that you were the one boasting about implementing the highest possible security measure for a financial institute. That's kind of asking for these kind of comments. Maybe you should leave those kind of details out.

Comment: I would normally do, but Sir, I was definately not boasting, I did mention the same to re-present the amount of "over thinking / paranoidness" I am doing at the moment. I don't really ask security related questions maybe you see these sort of "boastings" often, but I surely dont. so I am sorry if it sent out a wrong message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's keep to the question at hand:

> 1. Is the iv is safe to sent to frontend (iv + "." + encData)?

Well, yes. The IV may be public knowledge; as long as it is unique and - in the case of CBC mode encryption - random then this is fine. Of course, the IV and encData should be suitably encoded, for instance using hex (as in the linked answer) or base 64. This is not often done as the IV is always 16 bytes for AES, so it is easy to simply prefix the binary IV to the encData instead.

Beware of hackers changing the input; if the dot or colon is removed then you may have just an array of one element and accessing the ciphertext may result in an error or the decryption of empty data.

> 2. How should the password be generated? How about a SHA256 of (e.g. user's password that I store in db at signup)

No, you should use a password hash for that; SHA-256 is a cryptographically secure hash but not a password hash such as PBKDF2, bcrypt, scrypt or Argon2. And if you want to store something in the DB, then please do not let that be the AES secret key generated from the password.

---

This does not in any way invalidate any of the concerns in the [answer of TheGreatContini](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46332471/589259). This is not security advice, just the cryptography related advice you asked for.

Comment: the term password is used only because in the linked SO question, the term password is used instead of the key. and I am not really interpreting it as a "password". right now my test code to generate a random key looks like this const randomKey = crypto.randomBytes(256).toString('hex'); and is different for each user (generated at signup, and will be changed if user changes password / wants to logout of all devices)

Comment: Can you please confirm my action on the seconf question based on the comment above? also thanks for your answer, but I would really be glad if you can give me some advice too.

Comment: I plan to use this random key to encrypt user's session tokens

Comment: If the key is already random and of the right size then there is no need for putting it into a hash function.

Answer (score 2):

You may **want** AES encryption, but encryption is not what you **need**!  For the security of your application, message integrity is more important than encryption.

Encryption does not generally provide message integrity (see section 7 of [Top 10 Developer Crypto Mistakes](https://littlemaninmyhead.wordpress.com/2017/04/22/top-10-developer-crypto-mistakes/)) unless you specifically use a mode of operation that provides it (such as GCM mode).  Therefore, the solution you are designing in inherently wrong.  More info in footnote (!) below.

Understand what you need -- message integrity + encryption, or message integrity only.  If it is message integrity only, then use HMAC.

Another thing you need to understand is that functions like AES and HMAC do not use passwords, instead they use cryptographic keys.  See section 6 of [Top 10 Developer Crypto Mistakes](https://littlemaninmyhead.wordpress.com/2017/04/22/top-10-developer-crypto-mistakes/).

It is not clear whether your question on IV matters, given that your approach is wrong, but to answer it anyway, the IV does not need to be secret.  See section 2 of Top 10 Developer Crypto Mistakes.

I generally agree with the comments above: use JWT the way it was meant to be used rather than trying to build your own solution.  JWT has a claim reserved for [expiration](https://jwt.io/introduction/), so there is no reason not to.

footnote (!): If you want to see how confusion between message integrity and encryption gets abused, you can try [this exercise](https://pentesterlab.com/exercises/ecb/online) from Pentester Labs (unfortunately it requires a subscription, but it is cheap).  Granted that this is for ECB mode, a similar concept can work for CBC mode.

Comment: Thank you for sharing that good of an article, so to my understanding if i use my method then the tokens generated can be altered in a way so as to they change the data that is encrypted which can cause unforseen issues. but I also take a specific precaution i.e. to store all the tokens that I have ever generated into a nosql db and verify that the token recieved is one of the tokens I have generated. (i do not store it next to userId but rather just a token table, generation date and isValid) I Invalidate token when they expire or user logs out. I use this same precaution for JWT too as ....

Comment: I beleive that the same is true for JWT as well.

Comment: also the term password is used only because in the linked SO question, the term password is used instead of the key. and I am not really interpreting it as a "password". right now my test code to generate a random key looks like this `const randomKey = crypto.randomBytes(256).toString('hex');` and is different for each user (generated at signup, and will be changed if user changes password / wants to logout of all devices)

Comment: @RohitHazra What you are saying is fine (checking the token against the db), but then I do not understand why you need encryption at all.  Just generated a random token and store it in db.  Encryption is not improving anything here.

Comment: I am putting some data inside which I need on my authenticator which is basically what user it is, create date and some more data that my authenticator usesto determine various things and take actions such as return refresh-token.

Comment: what made re-think is (google why you should not use JWT) so many articles against JWT making me rethink the same. What are your thoughts?

Comment: @RohitHazra It depends what you are trying to do.  If you are trying to avoid a DB, then JWTs for sessions is one option.  If you have a DB already, then JWTs may not be less than ideal over traditional session management.  My last comment ("Just generated a random token and store it in db") is more like traditional session management and did not involve JWTs.  I don't understand why you can't put the data in the db rather than in the token itself.

Comment: data is in SQL, tokens are in NoSQL, either I duplicate the data or use something like JWT.